# Gupta SQL Base driver on Ubuntu

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu-14.04, driver, sqlbase

I know that Gupta SQL Base driver should not work with Ubuntu but with other Linux versions.
But have anyone got it working with Ubuntu?
I need to connect from Ubuntu machine to remote Gupta SQL Base database with php.
Maybe some third party driver managers? (iODBC and unixODBC?)

Answer (score 0):

You may already know about the Gupta user forum , but if not , and to save replicating a whole load of stuff , go here: [Gupta SQLBase v Ubuntu posts](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportforum/search.php?keywords=Ubuntu)
 to see lots of Ububtu / SQLBase bits that may be useful.

Comment: Note there are 2 pages of posts